# Turning on WiFi callback function in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-broadcast

I am developing an Android Application where I am sending an E-Mail when the user hits a certain activity in my Application. I can send E-Mails properly using an AsyncTask. However, I want to ensure that the user is actually online when this happens.

I also know that I can programmatically turn the WiFi as such:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
boolean wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();

if(!wifiEnabled){
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
}

//I can then do my async task here
```

However, it takes time for Android to connect to a network and establish connection. So when the async task fails because the device is offline.

Now, my questions are:

1. Is there a way for the application to know if the WiFi is already connected *without using BroadCast Receivers*? I know I can use Broadcast Receivers to check if the device is connected already. However, I think it's too cumbersome for my purposes. I am looking for something like a callback function, similar to those used in ExtJS frameworks when syncing records to a store/database.
2. If there is no callback function in Android, is it possible to have a Broadcast Receiver call your applications function *only when the application is active*? What I mean by this is that I'd want my Broadcast Receiver to call a function (E-Mail sending function) in my activity only when my application is active. I don't want it to call the function whenever the WiFi State changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for the application to know if the WiFi is already connected without using BroadCast Receivers?

If you mean a method to check if wifi is connected right now or not you can use this:

```
private boolean isWifiConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    return wifiInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

}
```

but for "getting aware of changes" to wifi state there is no way but using a broadcast reciever.

> is it possible to have a Broadcast Receiver call your applications function only when the application is active?

Yes. You can use `registerReceiver` and `unRegisterReceiver` methods of `Activity`. Just register your intended receiver in `onCreate` and unRegister it in `onDestroy` method of your activity.

example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wifi State Changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
```